# Laravel Route to controller with argument

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm trying to have clean URLs with out the ID displayed. For example, I currently have:

```
/Article/2 
/Article/3 
...
```

Instead I want those urls to switch to something like this:

```
/Article/2/ -> /My_Super_Awesome_Article/  
/Article/3/ -> /Another_Cool_Article
```

My route looks like this:

```
Route::resource('/article', 'ArticleController');
```

And the controller like this:

```
class MenuController extends \BaseController {

    public function show($id)
    {
            $page = Model::FindOrFail($id);
            return View::make('article.show')->withPage($page);
    }

    // more functions
```

===================================================

## WHAT WORKS BUT I THINK IS A BAD WAY OF DOING IT:

I figure out a way to do this... but this is for sure not the best approach. This is the technique I'm currently using to substitute:

In the controller, I add this

```
public function Clean_Url_20()
    {
            $page = Model::FindOrFail( 20 );
            return View::make('article.show')->withPage($page);
    }
```

And in the routes, I use this:

```
Route::get('/My_Super_Cool_URL', 'ArticleController@Clean_Url_20');
```

So... Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lack flexibility if you give every single article a route. You have to define 1000 routes if you have 1000 articles.

Why not define these routes in another way? For example:

```
Route::get('article/{articleSlug}','ArticlesController@show');
```

In your controller you just use the slug to find a particular article.

By the way, you can use Str::slug() to format your article titles when you are preparing your article data.

Comment: `You have to define 1000 routes if you have 1000 articles.` or use 'capture all' route as the last one and find corresponding item by it.

Comment: Yeah, using where clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/My_Super_Awesome_Article/{id}', array('as' => 'my.article.show', 'uses' => 'ArticleController@show'));
```

your route was wrong. give an attention to the `{id}`

Comment: how will you differentiate between each article then?